# Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors?

Tags: plsql, triggers

I am trying to implement Trigger that raises an User Defined Error Message and does not allow  the update and Insert operation in the database.I am new to pl/sql i refereed some code from the internet and try to implement.My code is running is fine as i can not update/insert into database but still i am unable to get my user defined message and also i am getting this warning.

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors ?
```

This is the table :

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 ID                                                 NUMBER(5)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(10)
 DEPOT_ADDRESS                                      VARCHAR2(15)
```

here is my code :

```
create or replace trigger cleaner_before_update_insert
for update or insert on cleaner
compound trigger
count binary_integer;

before statement is 
begin
    count:=0;
end before statement;

after each row is 
begin 
count :=count +1;
end after each row;

after statement is 
begin
    if count > 0 then
        raise_application_error( -20001,'Update/insert operation can not be completed ');  
    end if;   
 end after statement;  

 end cleaner_before_update;
 /
```

can anyone help me figure out what is the problem here and way to fix it.
thanks in advance.

Even after compilation of the code it is giving me this error.

```
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CLEANER_BEFORE_UPDATE_INSERT", line 18 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger                                         
'SYSTEM.CLEANER_BEFORE_UPDATE_INSERT'
```

Comment: The compilation error message should suggest what needs fixing.

Comment: I am unable to figure out where is the error can you help me ?

Comment: So the tool you are using does not display compilation errors automatically, you have googled _"how to view compilation errors in PL/SQL"_ and got nowhere, you found nothing in the documentation, and this is the first thing you have ever coded?

Comment: Have you tried to understand your code?. The exception you are raising will display the entire stack of error messages on Insert/update. It does display the user defined message along with other messages.That is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your `TRIGGER` block.

- The name of the Trigger `cleaner_before_update_insert` does not match with the `cleaner_before_update` after the final `end` statement.
- `COUNT` is an SQL keyword which is not allowed to be used as a variable in PL/SQL.You would receive the error - `Error(10,11): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'COUNT' may be used inside a SQL statement only`

So, here is the modified code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cleaner_before_update_insert FOR UPDATE OR
  INSERT ON cleaner compound TRIGGER 
v_count binary_integer;
  before STATEMENT
IS
BEGIN
  v_count:=0;
END before STATEMENT;
AFTER EACH row
IS
BEGIN
  v_count :=v_count +1;
END AFTER EACH row;
AFTER STATEMENT
IS
BEGIN
  IF v_count > 0 THEN
    raise_application_error( -20001,'Update/insert operation can not be completed ');
  END IF;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END cleaner_before_update_insert;
/
```

Comment: It is still giving me error of this                                                        ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.CLEANER_BEFORE_UPDATE_INSERT", line 18
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
'SYSTEM.CLEANER_BEFORE_UPDATE_INSERT'

Comment: exactly where do i need to add exception.

Comment: That is a different error. Previously the code wouldn't compile due to syntax errors, now it is preventing an insert as designed (`v_count > 0`). The error message should have indicated this line.

Comment: @Sachin, That is not what you described in the problem. You wrote the script  to raise `EXCEPTION` when `count > 0`, it is being raised accordingly and that is what u r seeing. What exactly do you need to change or add now?. Please update accordingly in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly ,can you help me out now ?